# Solving recurrence relations with a squared term?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, contest-math, recursion

$F_{n+1} = F_n^2+2F_n$.
Is there a way to solve this equation with the standard technique of solving the associated quadratic? In general, when can I and when can I not use the "polynomial solution" to a recurrence equation.

For anyone wondering where this recurrence comes from see 1985 Putnam A3.

Comment: You generally want an initial condition as well.

Comment: $F_0 = x$, an arbitrary initial condition.

Comment: $F_n=(F_0+1)^{2^n}-1$

Comment: @AmrAhmad Where'd you figure that out? lol

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, Isn't this obvious?!

Comment: I suppose it is...

Comment: Thanks, I feel silly for not seeing this myself. What if I got something scarier like: $F_{n+1} = 2F_n^3-F_n^2+F_n-1+2$?

Comment: First you decide if its possible to apply the trick mentioned in the below answers.  Else you, well... idk.  Not sure if there's a dupe out there, but you might be interested in asking for the closed form for the recurrence relation $a_{n+1}=a_n^2+ba_n+c$

Comment: For powers greater than 4 there isn't any closed form but below 4 I am not sure about anything, thanks I will ask about that to see if anyone knows.

Comment: After shifting by a constant so that we have $G_{n+1} = G_n^2 + C$ for real constant $C,$ there are just two values of $C$ for which we get anything nice: $C=0$ or $C=-2.$ For any other value of $C,$ we can get an approximation for $\frac{\log G_n}{2^n}$ but nothing more precise.

Comment: @Will Jagy You are right : I will add that the best proof that there is no simple solution is that in general $z_{n+1}=z_n^2+C$ is the typical sequence for building Mandelbrot's fractals (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set).

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks.

Comment: @WillJagy Are you able to provide any references for any approximations of $\frac{\log G_n}{2^n}$? In particular, I am interested in how fast the sequence increases asymptotically (or an upper bound) when $C=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$F_{n+1}+1=(F_n+1)^2\\\implies F_n+1=(F_0+1)^{2^n}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$F_{n+1}+1=(F_n+1)^2$$ and from here we can get, which you wish.